# firebase-python, returning the value of latest update to Firebase?

Tags: python, firebase

Let me start with saying, I have never coded in python before.

I am looking at using https://github.com/shariq/firebase-python to connect to my Firebase database.   I am using IFTTT to push data from another source into Firebase.   When an update happens, I want it to be automatically pushed to my python code.

I have the following:

```
import firebase
updatesUrl = 'baseball/updates'
updatesSubscription = firebase.subscriber(updatesUrl, refreshDisplay())

def refreshDisplay():
    # how do i get the value of the last update here?
```

Comment: Does this work for you? I'm also working on firebase with Python.

Comment: I never got any response on this question.   

I ended up abandoning this route anyway, because I discovered the IFTTT source was not sending frequent enough updates.   

I still would love to find a valid response though as I can think of other uses for it.

Answer (score 1):

Using firebase for python seems to be bit tricky.
The major drawback is that after subscribing to a URL, the subscriber polls firebase once in 15 minutes.

Here's what you can do with your code:

```
import firebase
updatesUrl = 'https://<app-name>.firebaseio.com/baseball/update.json'
updatesSubscription = firebase.subscriber(updatesUrl, refreshDisplay)

def refreshDisplay(json_data):
    j = json.loads(json.dumps(json_data))  
    print j
```

After executing the python code, open your firebase database and make some changes in the field that you wish to monitor.
You'll receive the updated value on python console roughly after 15 minutes like

```
[u'put', {u'path': u'/', u'data': u'Hope thie helps'}]
```

Suggestion: Use PubNub for this purpose instead of firebase.

Comment: Isn't there any way to reduce that time to few seconds?

Comment: I tried to look through the code but couldn't find anything to reduce the time limit. However when I used pubnub for the same purpose, it worked like a charm.
If you want to stick to firebase, try implementing a subscriber via node js or java and then let node js or java code invoke your python scripts and functions. I don't know about how efficient it will be, but give it a try as there are lot of resources on it.

Comment: Thanks... I'll see